# The installed java is version 7u65, yet the ubuntu package is 7u71, why the discrepancy?

Tags: java, openjdk

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and need to use Java 7 update 71. It seems like openjdk has been updated in the Trusty repos to update 71, yet even if I install the update java seems to still be at version u65.

```
moorepants@moorepants-2170p:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
moorepants@moorepants-2170p:~$ aptitude show openjdk-7-jre
Package: openjdk-7-jre                   
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Multi-Arch: same
Version: 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
Priority: optional
Section: java
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 662 k
Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), libasound2 (>= 1.0.16), libc6 (>= 2.14), libcups2 (>= 1.4.0), libfontconfig1 (>=
         2.9.0), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libgif4 (>= 4.1.4), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.16.0), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.8.0), libjpeg8 (>= 8c), libpango-1.0-0
         (>= 1.14.0), libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4), libx11-6, libxext6, libxi6, libxrender1, libxtst6, libxrandr2, libxinerama1, libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1,
         libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2)
Recommends: libgnome2-0, libgnomevfs2-0, libgconf2-4, fonts-dejavu-extra
Suggests: icedtea-7-plugin
Conflicts: icedtea-gcjwebplugin (< 1.0-1ubuntu4), icedtea-gcjwebplugin (< 1.0-1ubuntu4)
Breaks: openjdk-7-jre (!= 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
Replaces: openjdk-7-jre-headless (< 7u65-2.5.1-0~), openjdk-7-jre-headless (< 7u65-2.5.1-0~), openjdk-7-jre (< 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
Provides: java-runtime, java2-runtime, java5-runtime, java6-runtime, java7-runtime
Description: OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
 Full Java runtime environment - needed for executing Java GUI and Webstart programs. Using Hotspot JIT. 

 The packages are built using the IcedTea build support and patches from the IcedTea project.
Homepage: http://openjdk.java.net/

moorepants@moorepants-2170p:~$  sudo update-alternatives --config java 
[sudo] password for moorepants: 
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
```

What am I missing? Why isn't the java version u71?

Comment: Add the output of `which java` or close the question, if there is no longer a problem ;)